# Polymorphism regarding argument types to methods

Tags: c#

I think I have a quite common problem, but I can really come up with a solution for it..

Imagine this class:

```
public class ListHandlerBase
{
    public virtual void Add(object item)
    {
        // XXX
    }
}


public class ListHandler : ListHandlerBase
{
    List<object> ObjectList = new List<object>();
    List<string> StringList = new List<string>();
    List<int> IntList = new List<int>();

    public override void Add(object item)
    {
        HandleAdd(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(object item)
    {
        ObjectList.Add(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(string item)
    {
        StringList.Add(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(int item)
    {
        IntList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It have an Add method accepting the quite general type object. There is however several methods that can handle the object, but only "HandleAdd(object item)" will be called since item is of type object (even if its really a string). I would want some kind of virtual/override for this.

There is an ugly solution that may look like this:

```
    public void Add(object item)
    {
        if(item is string) HandleAdd((string)item);
        else if (item is int) HandleAdd((int)item);
        else HandleAdd(item);
    }
```

I would have to make a complete list of all types, and that doesn't sound like a nice solution to the problem.

Is there anyway I can get the "correct" method called in the way I want?

**Update:** To even complicate the problem a bit more I have added a base class. That is why I cant have multiple add methods, since the base class don't know what object types the ListHandler can accept. The classes that calls the ListHandler class does not know about its specifics. I also think i can answer my problem myself. Its a multiple dispatch problem and I don't think it can not be solved in C# without the visitor pattern.

Comment: I'd  suggest you to have a `Add` method overload for each type you need

Comment: Can you give a more 'real' example of a situation where you find yourself facing this problem? There may be a better design which means you don't have to deal with this in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I think this is a code smell. I would try to find some alternate design that doesn't require this. But it's hard to help you with that without understanding the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Now, to your actual question:

> It's a multiple dispatch problem and I don't think it can not be solved in C# without the visitor pattern.

It's not quite the common version of the multiple dispatch problem: the types you're dispatching on aren't under your control (so you can't add `AcceptVisitor()` to them) and the list of types also is different for each derived type (so you can't create a fixed `IVisitor`).

But you actually *can* solve this in C#, using `dynamic`. The exact solution depends on whether you're willing to make the `HandleAdd()` overloads public or not. If you can do that, then just call `HandleAdd()` from your `Add()`, using `dynamic` for `this` and `item`:

```
public abstract class ListHandlerBase
{
    public void Add(object item)
    {
        ((dynamic)this).HandleAdd((dynamic)item);
    }
}

public class ListHandler : ListHandlerBase
{
    List<object> ObjectList = new List<object>();
    List<string> StringList = new List<string>();
    List<int> IntList = new List<int>();

    public void HandleAdd(object item)
    {
        ObjectList.Add(item);
    }

    public void HandleAdd(string item)
    {
        StringList.Add(item);
    }

    public void HandleAdd(int item)
    {
        IntList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If you want to keep `HandleAdd()` private, then you will have to call it from the derived class itself. This means making `Add()` abstract in the base class and implement it using `dynamic` in each derived class (and this time, you don't need `dynamic` on `this`):

```
public abstract class ListHandlerBase
{
    public abstract void Add(object item);
}

public class ListHandler : ListHandlerBase
{
    …

    public override void Add(object item)
    {
        HandleAdd((dynamic)item);
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of dynamic, but this solution actually do the job! It forces the application to select the correct version of HandleAdd at run time (when I know the type of the object), rather than at compile time. I did not know you could do this. It was the answer I were looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add overloads of `Add` for the other types you want to handle

```
public class ListHandler
{
    List<object> ObjectList = new List<object>();
    List<string> StringList = new List<string>();
    List<int> IntList = new List<int>();

    public void Add(object item)
    {
        HandleAdd(item);
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        HandleAdd(item);
    }

    public void Add(int item)
    {
        HandleAdd(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(object item)
    {
        ObjectList.Add(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(string item)
    {
        StringList.Add(item);
    }

    private void HandleAdd(int item)
    {
        IntList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As Elvedin pointed out - of course if your methods don't do more than this, there is no point in keeping the separate `HandleAdd()` methods, you could rather just add them to the appropriate list directly.

Comment: It's OK, but using two methods is unnecessary, remove `HandleAdd` if you can.

Comment: That is true :) But maybe there is some other reason to split this, so I kept it close to the question

Comment: I understand that, but the user who asked maybe would not. It's always a good practice to keep details. (You've already got +1)